# Post form action form raw php page to laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project with a regular ( .php) page. Is it possible to post some form data form this regular PHP page (not blade file) to a laravel controller action?

Comment: Add the form, stick an input on the form, dd Post and see what happens.

Comment: What do you mean could explain further please?